facing issues with python module installation
i am gettinig error as : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'currency_converter'
i installed by command: pip3 install currency_converter
after instaltion show succesfull, even showing madule as exit on checking by: pip3 show currency_converter
after that use migration command then its show same error as abobe
Migration: python3 manage.py makemigrations
please help

Does this answer your question? Module not found - "No module named"

If you are using environments and multiple Python versions, then this might require a few extra configuration steps for executing scripts.

The distribution is named currency.converter. The address https://pypi.org/project/currency_converter/ redirects to https://pypi.org/project/currency.converter/ .
Inside the distribution there is a top-level package currency and inside it subpackage converter so your import should be import currency.converter.
The package requires Zope so most probably it wouldn't work with Django. The last release 0.5.5 was released in 2010. The package is old and abandoned, are you sure you want to use it?
